# Is this a COVID-19 reference in Kaguya-sama: Love Is War season 2?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

In season 2 episode 6 of *Kaguya-sama: Love Is War*, Miko Iino (a candidate for student council president election) says that her mother is busy distributing vaccines to a hotspot.

[image]

Does "hotspot" refers to the "heavily COVID-19 affected area"? Also "vaccines" may refer to an anti-COVID vaccine and so this statement can be relevant to the ongoing COVID pandemic. So, is the story of this anime progressing in the pandemic?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Unlikely.**

The anime is an adaptation of the manga, which is the canonical source. According to [Fandom Wiki](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_18), episode 18 (season 2 episode 6) adapts chapter 67-69 of the manga. This particular scene is from [chapter 68](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_68) titled *I Want to Make Miko Iino Smile* which was **published on 22 June 2017**, long before the COVID-19 outbreak happened.

Regarding the term "hot spot", it actually means "conflict hot spot". The original text in Japanese is [紛争地域](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%B4%9B%E4%BA%89%E5%9C%B0%E5%9F%9F) which means "disputed territory; conflict area".

The fan translation of this scene is

[image: chapter 68, page 1, panel 3]

> My mom's giving vaccines in a war zone,

which gives more context than a general term "hot spot".

Comment: Why is the manga "fan translated"? Has the manga ever officially translated and published in English?

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami the panel I used was taken from a random scanlation, so I don't know the credibility of its transation. The manga has been officially licensed and published in English by [Viz Media](https://www.viz.com/kaguya-sama-love-is-war) though.

Answer (score 7):

Nope. It is just a random coincidence.
This scene comes from [chapter 68](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_68) of the manga which was already published on 22 June 2017.
[image: First page of chapter 68]